# My code makes some memory increment, what is the cause?

Tags: qt, memory-leaks

Here is the table cleaning code:

```
void AudioAPI::clearTable(QTableWidget *songTable)
{
    songTable->clearContents();
    songTable->setRowCount(0);
}
```

2nd:

```
void AudioAPI::createSongFromPath(QString path, QTableWidget *songTable)
{
    TagLib::FileRef file(path.toLocal8Bit().data());

    TagLib::String title = file.tag()->title();
    TagLib::String artist = file.tag()->artist();

    songTable->insertRow(songTable->rowCount());
    songTable->setItem(songTable->rowCount() - 1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdWString(title.toWString())));
    songTable->setItem(songTable->rowCount() - 1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdWString(artist.toWString())));
    songTable->setItem(songTable->rowCount() - 1, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(path));
}
```

3rd (contains 2nd and 1st):

```
void AudioAPI::createListFromDir(QString path, QTableWidget *songTable)
{
   if (path != NULL)
   {
       bool check = 0;
       QDirIterator it(path, QStringList() << "*.mp3", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

       while (it.hasNext())
       {
           if (!check)
           {
               AudioAPI::clearTable(songTable);
               check = 1;
           }
           it.next();
           createSongFromPath(it.filePath(), songTable);
       }
   }
}
```

Running 3rd code multiple times caused memory increment, and i don't know if it was caused by my improperly coding or some technical glitch. Any help is appreciated to show me the point of the problem.

Comment: You allocate new memory on the heap by calling `createSongFromPath`. Each new row will theoretically increase the memory. Your code is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out of this case. Seems like i'm still lacking knowledge about C++ platform.